# Using grep to find string in two files?

Tags: linux, unix, command-line, terminal, grep

I would like to find a particular string in two text files - I know how to do it in a single file, but how do I select more than one file, the example below does it for a single text file, I want to search file myfile.txt and otherfile.txt

```
grep "redeem" /home/tom/myfile.txt
```

Comment: Use : `grep 'pattern' file1 file2 file...`

Comment: ooh i see will give that a shot nice one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this,

```
grep 'redeem' file1 file2 file3..
```

**Syntax:**

```
grep [OPTIONS] PATTERN [FILE...]
```

Normally, `grep` can do the `pattern` matching in more than one files.